# How to get the symbols of class members in object file?

Tags: c++, c++11, nm

Is there a way to get the symbols of class members using GNU nm?

Answer (score 3):

> While the GNU nm tool lists symbols for struct members

No, `nm` don't do that in general (even with `nm -C`). It is listing symbols which are either function names (including non-inlined constructors) or global variable names.

You may consider compiling and building your application with `g++ -g` (debug information) and parse the [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) sections in the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable.

Comment: Agreed. Even symbols of struct members are not listed.